# Excel Userform Multiple Combobox

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel UserForm with (2) ComboBoxes. Both comboboxes list information from the "H" range, and ComboBox2 should list info from the "V" range. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? I'm still very new to VBA, and I know my code is probably sloppy. Please keep it easy to understand, thanks!

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
LookAhead.Caption = Span & " Week Look Ahead"

' Sets range for ComboBox lists
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rng2 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("H2:H65536")
        For Each r In rng
            AddUnique r.value
        Next r
    Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("V2:V65536")
        For Each r2 In rng2
            AddUnique r2.value
        Next r2

    End Sub

' Filter out duplicates in lists for UserForm ComboBoxes

Sub AddUnique(value As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim inList As Boolean

    inList = False
    With Me.ComboBox1
        For i = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ComboBox1.List(i) = value Then
                inList = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If Not inList Then
            .AddItem value
        End If
    End With

    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim inList2 As Boolean

    inList2 = False
    With Me.ComboBox2
        For ii = 0 To Me.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ComboBox2.List(ii) = value Then
                inList2 = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ii

        If Not inList2 Then
            .AddItem value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: You aren't asking a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion) Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and **what is wrong**... then we can try to help

Comment: What is wrong is listed above: "Both comboboxes list information from the "H" range, and ComboBox2 should list info from the "V" range." I seem to be having trouble adding  code for another range for combobox2. Combobox1 should list data from the "H" column, and Combobox2 should list data from the "V" column. I'm not sure what the proper way is to do this.

Comment: I understand that both comboboxes have identical lists, and that the lists have information from the "H" range. Do they also have data from the "V" range? It would probably be at the bottom of the list, if they do.

Comment: Yes they do - the "H" range is at the top, the "V" range is at the bottom on both comboboxes. I'm trying to reverse engineer code that I find, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! I did this and it seems to be working:

```
Dim Cl As Range
Dim Area As String
Dim TCR As String

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each Cl In Sheets("Projects").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(22).DataBodyRange
            If Not .exists(Cl.value) Then .Add Cl.value, Nothing
        Next Cl
         ComboBox1.Clear
         ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
         .RemoveAll
    End With

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each Cl In Sheets("Projects").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange
            If Not .exists(Cl.value) Then .Add Cl.value, Nothing
        Next Cl
         ComboBox2.Clear
         ComboBox2.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
         .RemoveAll
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `AddUnique` sub, you were passing through the value to add as a parameter, and then adding that value to both `ComboBox1` and `ComboBox2`. Since you want to add different values to each combobox, the code needs to be slightly adjusted so you can also pass through some way of determining which combobox you want the value to be added to.

One way is in the code I've included below. Instead of directly referencing each combobox, I added a combobox parameter. Then, when `AddUnique` is called, you can also specify which combobox the value should be added to.

Another alternative (assuming you only ever have two comboboxes you're using here) would be to have a boolean parameter, which when true would add the value to `Combobox1`, and if false then the value would be added to `Combobox2`.

Or instead of actually passing in the combobox, change the parameter to a string for the control name, and access the control via `Me.Controls(control_name)`

---

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
LookAhead.Caption = Span & " Week Look Ahead"

' Sets range for ComboBox lists
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rng2 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("H2:H65536")
        For Each r In rng
            AddUnique r.value, Me.ComboBox1
        Next r
    Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("V2:V65536")
        For Each r2 In rng2
            AddUnique r2.value, Me.ComboBox2
        Next r2

    End Sub

' Filter out duplicates in lists for UserForm ComboBoxes

Sub AddUnique(value As Variant, combobox as Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim inList As Boolean

    inList = False
    With combobox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .List(i) = value Then
                inList = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If Not inList Then
            .AddItem value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```